# What is the data-value attribute in SVG?

Tags: svg

I was looking at [this article](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg/)

And particularly this code,

```
    <svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph" aria-labelledby="title" role="img">
  <title id="title">A line chart showing some information</title>
<g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
  <line x1="90" x2="90" y1="5" y2="371"></line>
</g>
<g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
  <line x1="90" x2="705" y1="370" y2="370"></line>
</g>
  <g class="labels x-labels">
  <text x="100" y="400">2008</text>
  <text x="246" y="400">2009</text>
  <text x="392" y="400">2010</text>
  <text x="538" y="400">2011</text>
  <text x="684" y="400">2012</text>
  <text x="400" y="440" class="label-title">Year</text>
</g>
<g class="labels y-labels">
  <text x="80" y="15">15</text>
  <text x="80" y="131">10</text>
  <text x="80" y="248">5</text>
  <text x="80" y="373">0</text>
  <text x="50" y="200" class="label-title">Price</text>
</g>
<g class="data" data-setname="Our first data set">
  <circle cx="90" cy="192" data-value="7.2" r="4"></circle>
  <circle cx="240" cy="141" data-value="8.1" r="4"></circle>
  <circle cx="388" cy="179" data-value="7.7" r="4"></circle>
  <circle cx="531" cy="200" data-value="6.8" r="4"></circle>
  <circle cx="677" cy="104" data-value="6.7" r="4"></circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

And I was wondering what `data-value` attribute was. When I tried googling for some documentation I only found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/data-*), which said:

> The data-* SVG attributes are called custom data attributes. They let SVG markup and its resulting DOM share information that standard attributes can't, usually for scripting purposes. Their custom data are available via the SVGElement interface of the element the attributes belong to, with the SVGElement.dataset property.

And since I'm new at SVG, I wasn't sure what this meant. If someone could elucidate me on what `data-value` is that would be great!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes